# How can I fill my array in JavaScript depending on user input?

Tags: javascript

How can I fill my array depending on user input instead of changing this array manualy in JavaScript?

How can I link my form in HTML to my javaScript ?

```js
let move = ["L", "L", "R", "F", "N"];
let lastElement = move.slice(-1);
console.log(lastElement);

function finalPosition(move) {
    let countUp = 0, countDown = 0;
    let countLeft = 0, countRight = 0;
    let l = move.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {

        if (move[i] == 'F')
            countUp++;

        else if (move[i] == 'B')
            countDown++;

        else if (move[i] == 'L')
            countLeft++;

        else if (move[i] == 'R')
            countRight++;
    }
    document.write("Final Position: (" + (countRight - countLeft) + ", " + (countUp - countDown) + "," + lastElement + ")");
}

finalPosition(move);
```

Comment: You need to read a tutorial about how to get information from input fields in JavaScript.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok two questions in one:

- > *How can I fill my array depending on user input instead of changing this array manualy in JavaScript?*

  Use `.push()` to add a value to your Array. For more info see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- > *How can I link my form in HTML to my javaScript?*

  1. Add an id to the form.
  2. Then load the form with:

     ```js
     const theForm = document.getElementById("theFormId");
     ```

     Then you can work with the form in JavaScript.

Comment: it did not solve my problem due my 2 questions are related to eachother.

I have a form and I want to get the user' string and when the user pushes the button, I want to take the last string and add it to my array.